# Powershell: Display last X lines of a log that match a criteria and keep watching the file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to watch a log file for occurrences of a word ("Purge"). 
I want to display the last 10 *matching* lines (at the time the command runs) and keep watching the file for newly appended lines that match the criteria.

So far, I got *something* working with PowerShell:

```
get-content .\CallAudit.Engine.log -tail 10 -Wait | where {$_ -match "Purge"}
```

This works, but it gets the last (any) 10 lines and only then applies the filter.

I want to

- get only the *matching* last 10 lines
- have the command keep watching the file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Tail 10` won't help you because your `purge`-filter is executed after it has read the last 10 lines (which may or may not contain `purge`).

I would split this into two calls. One to list the last 10 values, and one to monitor.

```
Get-Content -Path .\CallAudit.Engine.log | Where-Object {$_ -match "Purge"} | Select-Object -Last 10
Get-Content -Path .\CallAudit.Engine.log -Wait -Tail 0 | Where-Object {$_ -match "Purge"}
```

Comment: Nice, looks very 'common sense'. Is there a way to concatenate the two lists of results, making this a "one-liner"?

Comment: Why? The idea was to split them in the first place to avoid overcomplicated `where`/`foreach`-loops to achieve a simple thing. Readability should always be priority. :-) If you really need it in one line, add `;` after the first line to end the current command/line and join the lines. Ex.. `get-content .. | where .. | Select -last 10; get-content -wait | where.... `

Comment: Why? Because I'm curious about the syntax :)

Comment: That's why I added the solution (joining the lines with `;`). However, it runs the same way as it would With linebreaks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the right tool for the job which is `less.exe`. It is most often used as a pager (equivalent to `more` on Windows) but it is awesome tool that can be used to quickly examine files and monitor them.

For your case you need to use the following less options:

- `&/` - filtering lines (the same as `where-object .... match`)
- `F`  - forward forever (the same as`gc .. -Wait -Tail`)

If you file is `log.txt` and you need to monitor for numbers only this is the command:

```
less.exe +"&[0-9]+`nF"  log.txt
```

This is how output looks like:
[image]

Change `[0-9]+` to match your pattern and leave everything else. Another example, just show build errors real time and hide everything else

```
less.exe +"&^ERROR`nF" build.log
```

You can get less from chocolatey: `cinst less`.

The benefits of using less over pure powershell here are:

- cross platform
- less is very powerful and used by number of windows tools such as git, powershell community extensions etc. Its good to have such tool in your arsenal.

Comment: +1 for the info and very useful for a dev box. My scenario involves RDP'ing into possibly production machines, possibly the clients' machines, so installing 3rd party tools (Chocolatey + packages) may be unwanted or downright impossible. That's why I prefer PS -- or any other solution using "built-in" tools

Comment: You could copy less.exe to production or use it from the share directly. Its a single file ~100KB.